# Winston + Morgan Logging Production EC2

Tags: node.js, git, logging, amazon-ec2, winston

The below is my `Winston` Configuration, we are using `morgan` with it.

```
var winston = require('winston');
winston.emitErrs = true;

var logger = new winston.Logger({
    transports: [
        new winston.transports.File({
            level: 'info',
            filename: __dirname+'/log/all-logs.log',
            handleExceptions: true,
            json: true,
            maxsize: 5242880, //5MB
            maxFiles: 1500,
            colorize: false
        }),
        new winston.transports.Console({
            level: 'debug',
            handleExceptions: true,
            json: false,
            colorize: true,
            'timestamp' : true
        })
    ],
    exitOnError: false
});

module.exports = logger;
module.exports.stream = {
    write: function(message, encoding){
        logger.info(message);
    }
};
```

This works, I had two primary questions.

> 1. I wanted to understand in `NODE.JS` `Production` Environment on `Amazon AWS EC2` Server, is it ideal for the `log` files to be generated in the
>      same Project Folder or somewhere outside the project hierarchy?
> 2. When using `Morgan` along with `Winston`, how do we commit the code using `git` for ignoring the `log` files? They get regenerated even if they are deleted.

We are starters in Winston and don't have any clue about how to go about the `git` and `log system` simultaneously. Adding the `log` files to `.gitignore` file doesn't help either.

Also any general advice for `winston` logging on the `EC2` Platform ?

Comment: If the log files are already present in git then .gitignore has no effect. Remove the files using `git rm <filename>` , add the files or folder containing those files to .gitignore and commit